# Excel VBA: Get the right date into a cell using DatePicker

Tags: vba, excel

I have a UserForm with a DatePicker control in it.
It works fine, except when copying the selected date to the spreadsheet.
This is the code:

```
Range("A1").Value = UserForm1.DTPicker1.Value
```

Which returns:

```
00:00:00
```

In cell A1, no matter what date has been selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cell formatting might be set to Time instead of Date.

Try changing that to see if it works.

Also, make formatting 'General' AFTER this step, to see if anything has been pasted in "A1".

Answer (score 0):

You should need an intermediate variable to get it, like below:

```
t = Me.DTPicker1.Value
ws.Range("A1") = t
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that the command to transfer the data is located in the same form or page of a multipage form as the DTPicker itself.

For some reason it wont work when the two are separated and will display a zero in the target cell. That zero is the "time" part of the date which has been switched off. Although the "Date" part refuses to transfer over, for some reason the time does, and so that zero time is read in the cell as time zero which is mid-day.

So in summary:

Keep the DTPicker and transfer control on the same page and that should solve the problem.

The code is pretty simple. It's

```
Sheet1.Range("AA9") = Me.DTPicker1.Value
```